# Django_filters check if value/connection exists

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-filter, django-filters

Hej!

I'm looking for an option on how to filter IF the value exists, the value itself is irrelevant. To filter all institutions with the given AddOn.

A checkbox would be best where I can 'check' if I want my database entries filtered by this variable or not.
If it's 'checked' I want to filter all entries which have the given variable and if it's not checked I don't want to filter.

```
models.py

class Institution(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_("Name of the institution"),
        max_length=200,
    )
    abbreviation = models.CharField(  # null=False, but "" allowed. Is Django convention
        verbose_name=_("Acronym"),
        max_length=25,
        blank=True,
        help_text=_("if applicable"),
    )

class AddInstitutionMorebio(models.Model):
    institution = models.OneToOneField(
        Institution,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="institution_morebio"
    )
    id_morebio = models.CharField(
        max_length=6,
        unique = True
    )
```

```
filters.py

class InstitutionFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(method='name_filter', label="Name")

   morebio_id = AddInstitutionMorebio.objects.filter(id_morebio=True)  # this does nothing
```

Does someone know what to do?
Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: You question is confusing. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I have a model (for institutions) with multiple related models and I want a filter option (in my view) where a user can click a checkbox to only see the institutions which have info in the additional/related model. It doesn't matter WHAT the entry/value is, it's only important if it's there or not.

Comment: Does the value of checkbox come from frontend ?

Comment: yes, the user should be able to decide if they want to filter for the AddOn or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
morebio_id = BooleanFilter(lookup_expr='isnull', field_name='institution_morebio__id_morebio', label='MoreBio')
```

is the solution I found. Just if someone else is struggeling with the same.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, you can use `exclude` with `exact` or `iexact`.

Instead of:

```
.filter(id_morebio=True)
```

Try:

```
.exclude(id_morebio__exact="")
```

Notice, that there is double underscore `__` before `exact`. It basically will exclude all entries, that have exactly `""` as `id_morebio` value.

Comment: ah. I don't even get a checkbox so far. It literally does nothing at the moment. 
Do you know how I can achieve that? Or how to integrate the exclude expression elsewhere in a filter?

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
I just can't find anything helpfull for my case. If I use a BooleanFilter I can't use an exclude method. It seems to only look for BooleanFields in my model (which I don't have). 
And with the `.exclude()` I don't get any filter field in my view. 
With a CharFilter I can use the 'icontains' or 'contains' but I can't find where I can put an exclude method. And I don't want a CharFilter. It doesn't have to be a Checkbox, but something suitable for my request. 
`widget=forms.CheckboxInput` is also not working. 
I'm not looking for a quick code :) doc would be fine!

Comment: Just instead of this: `morebio_id = AddInstitutionMorebio.objects.filter(id_morebio=True)`, try doing this: `morebio_id = AddInstitutionMorebio.objects.exclude(id_morebio__exact="")`. Now I see that you have `unique=True` - you have to get rid of this if you want to have many objects with `""` value. Your project is very chaotic.

Comment: I did. I just don't get any filter shown in my view.
And I can't get rid of the unique.

Comment: and I know that the project is chaotic. It's huge and I'm only responsible for bits and pieces. Complicated to work with.